# Remove specific json key,value pair from JSON aray from mysql column

Tags: json, mysql-5.7

I have a mysql table which has one JSON type column. I want to remove specific entry from nested JSON column which.
I have data like this

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "actions": [
        "GENERATE",
        "FAIL",
        "STOP"
      ],
      "isAdmin": true
    },
    {
      "actions": [
        "GENERATE",
        "FAIL",
        "STOP"
      ],
      "isAdmin": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I need it to be like this:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "actions": [
        "GENERATE",
        "FAIL",
        "STOP"
      ]
    },
    {
      "actions": [
        "GENERATE",
        "FAIL",
        "STOP"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

After trying bunch of mysql function I came up with partial solution. But this is not working for all the cases.

`UPDATE user_config SET user_perm = JSON_REMOVE(user_perm, '$.users[*].isAdmin');`
is giving error:
In this situation, path expressions may not contain the * and ** tokens.

If I try with
`UPDATE user_config SET user_perm = JSON_REMOVE(user_perm, '$.users[0].isAdmin');`, it working fine, but entries might having index 1,2,...

How should I change my query